# What's the two circles on Myspace for?

Tags: myspace

[image: My just.in]

When I click on it it becomes one circle, but doesn't explain what it's for.

Has anyone discovered what's it for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Two empty rings:** You're not connected.

**First ring full**, second empty: You're connected to the person, but he is not connected to you.

**First ring empty**, second full: The person is connected to you, but you have not connected to him.

**Single full ring**: The connection is mutual, reciprocated by both parties.

Comment: Thanks. How did you know about this?

Comment: i forget, here's the source [link](http://mashable.com/2012/12/06/new-myspace-guide/)